# SQL - Inster into with now() minus one day

Tags: sql, h2, date-arithmetic

I want change this request. Actualy this request insert into always 2021-11-11 at 10:50:00

```
INSERT INTO my_table(name, start_date) VALUES('test', '2021-11-11 10:50:00);
```

I use a script.sql for my H2 database (continous delivery). I want change my request to Now() minus one day at 10:50:00.

Comment: We'd need to know RDBMS and version.

Comment: H2 from com.h2database

Comment: @Martin, how to use 1st `DATEADD` and 2nd `DATEADD` in same action?

Comment: For future reference, "date arithmetic" is the term for what you're doing and will want to Google for.

Comment: @StéphaneGRILLON One of the things I've found while answering SQL questions for well over a decade here on SO is that for many people, they searched for an answer and came up with nothing because they didn't know what to search for. That's why I mentioned that the term is "date arithmetic".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtract a day from the current date, then add the time.

```
INSERT INTO my_table (name, start_date) VALUES 
('test', DATEADD(DAY, -1, CURRENT_DATE) + TIME '10:50:00');
```

Comment: Where is `at 10:50:00` part please?

Comment: Oh, okay. that specific time is mandatory. lemme think...

Comment: @StéphaneGRILLON Changed. Does it work?

Comment: No, sorry. Syntax error in the instruction. `expected "YEAR, MONTH, DAY, HOUR, MINUTE, SECOND";`

Comment: I mix your reply with an other and it work. `DATEADD(DAY, -1, CURRENT_DATE) + TIME '10:50:00'` You can edit your reply if it is good for you.

Comment: That's cool. :)

Answer (score 1):

take a look at the [dateadd function](http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#dateadd)

```
DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATE'2021-11-11 10:50:00')
```

Answer (score 1):

cast the current datetime as date then add the time cast as datetime to the date

```
declare @date datetime=cast(GetDate()-1 as date)
declare @time time='10:50:00'
select
@date+cast(@time as datetime) current_at_10_50


INSERT INTO my_table (name, start_date) VALUES 
('test', @date+cast(@time as datetime));
```

Comment: sorry, I do not understand your answer. where is the `INSERT INTO my_table ...`?